# What's equivalent to [ alias cs='cd;ls' ] but with the argument to cs going to cd instead of ls?

Tags: linux, command-line

For instance, I want:

```
/tmp: $ cs /home
```

to perform 'cd /home; ls' and give:

```
user1 user2 user3 egfile.txt
/home: $
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't pass arguments to an alias, but you can to a function.

```
cs() {
cd "$@"
ls
}
```

Comment: Better: `cd "$@" && ls`, so that the function returns a nonzero status (and doesn't run `ls`) if `cd` fails. Even better: `builtin cd "$@" && ls`, which still works even if the function is called `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answered of @garyjohn and @Gilles with an `interactive?` check and elaborated on the `ls` output formatting.

Now you can safely add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

#### A basic version

```
#
# Replace every cd with cd+ls
#
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then  # if running interactively
  cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
  }
fi
```

---

#### A lovely version

Filters the output of `ls` so that only size, mtime, and name are displayed.

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then  # if running interactively
  cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" &&
    ls --color=always -lh | 
    awk '{ for(i=5; i<=NF; i++) {printf("%s ", $i)}; print ""} '  | 
    column -t  && echo
  }
fi
```

Comment: IMHO, "interactive?" checks are best done once in a rc file, with `[ "$PS1" ] || return` or `[[ $- == *i* ]] || return`, rather than wrapping everything in a very big `if`.

Comment: @grawity, I will leave the check in my answer just to be safe. Both a big `if` and `return` are valid ways. Thank you for the `$-` it seems to me a more reliable check. After all, one can use a shell interactively without a prompt. $PS always seemed artificial to me.

Comment: By the way, you don't need a `\ ` after pipes or `&&`/`||` operators.